# Como obtener el id tr del row que eh presionado ? jquery

Tags: jquery, html5

Hola chicos creo que estoy apunto de resolver lo que quiero , pero no eh podido dar con el id del row que estoy trabajando en la tabla.

Me hare explicar mejor tengo una tabla comun y sencilla pero si presiono un td se cambia a un input para poder edirtarla.

Lo que estoy realizando ahora si aprieto un td se convierte en un select y al cambiar la informacion del select se activa un window.location.replace que otra pagina pero que deberia llevar el id del tr de la columna que estoy presionando les mostrare.introducir el código aquí.

Lo que sucede es que me toma el id pero me toma el ultimo de la tabla no el del row que estoy presionando.

La funcion en donde estoy trabajando es $table.on('change', 'select.tabledit-input:visible') en esa parte agrego la sentencia para poder redirigir a otra pagina web.

```js
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Tabledit requires jQuery library.');
}

(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.Tabledit = function(options) {
        if (!this.is('table')) {
            throw new Error('Tabledit only works when applied to a table.');
        }

        var $table = this;

        var defaults = {
            url: window.location.href,
            inputClass: 'form-control input-sm',
            toolbarClass: 'btn-toolbar',
            groupClass: 'btn-group btn-group-sm',
            dangerClass: 'danger',
            warningClass: 'warning',
            mutedClass: 'text-muted',
            eventType: 'click',
            rowIdentifier: 'id',
            hideIdentifier: false,
            autoFocus: true,
            editButton: true,
            deleteButton: true,
            saveButton: true,
            restoreButton: true,
            buttons: {
                edit: {
                    class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default',
                    html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>',
                    action: 'edit'
                },
                delete: {
                    class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default',
                    html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>',
                    action: 'delete'
                },
                save: {
                    class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
                    html: 'Save'
                },
                restore: {
                    class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning',
                    html: 'Restore',
                    action: 'restore'
                },
                confirm: {
                    class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
                    html: 'Confirm'
                }
            },
            onDraw: function() { return; },
            onSuccess: function() { return; },
            onFail: function() { return; },
            onAlways: function() { return; },
            onAjax: function() { return; }
        };

        var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);

        var $lastEditedRow = 'undefined';
        var $lastDeletedRow = 'undefined';
        var $lastRestoredRow = 'undefined';

        /**
         * Draw Tabledit structure (identifier column, editable columns, toolbar column).
         *
         * @type {object}
         */
        var Draw = {
            columns: {
                identifier: function() {
                    // Hide identifier column.
                    if (settings.hideIdentifier) {
                        $table.find('th:nth-child(' + parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1 + '), tbody td:nth-child(' + parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1 + ')').hide();
                    }

                    var $td = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + (parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1) + ')');

                    $td.each(function() {
                        // Create hidden input with row identifier.
                        var span = '<span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
                        var input = '<input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" id="' + $(this).text() + '" name="' + settings.columns.identifier[1] + '" value="' + $(this).text() + '" disabled>';

                        // Add elements to table cell.
                        $(this).html(span + input);

                        // Add attribute "id" to table row.
                        $(this).parent('tr').attr(settings.rowIdentifier, $(this).text());
                    });
                },
                editable: function() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < settings.columns.editable.length; i++) {
                        var $td = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + (parseInt(settings.columns.editable[i][0]) + 1) + ')');

                        $td.each(function() {
                            // Get text of this cell.
                            var text = $(this).text();

                            // Add pointer as cursor.
                            if (!settings.editButton) {
                                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                            }

                            // Create span element.
                            var span = '<span class="tabledit-span">' + text + '</span>';

                            // Check if exists the third parameter of editable array.
                            if (typeof settings.columns.editable[i][2] !== 'undefined') {
                                // Create select element.
                                var input = '<select class="tabledit-input ' + settings.inputClass + '" name="' + settings.columns.editable[i][1] + '" id="' + settings.columns.editable[i][1] + '" style="display: none;" disabled>';

                                // Create options for select element.
                                $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(settings.columns.editable[i][2]), function(index, value) {
                                    if (text === value) {
                                        input += '<option value="' + index + '" selected>' + value + '</option>';
                                    } else {
                                        input += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                                    }
                                });

                                // Create last piece of select element.
                                input += '</select>';
                            } else {
                                // Create text input element.
                                var input = '<input class="tabledit-input ' + settings.inputClass + '" type="text" name="' + settings.columns.editable[i][1] + '" value="' + $(this).text() + '" style="display: none;" disabled>';
                            }

                            // Add elements and class "view" to table cell.
                            $(this).html(span + input);
                            $(this).addClass('tabledit-view-mode');
                       });
                    }
                },
                toolbar: function() {
                    if (settings.editButton || settings.deleteButton) {
                        var editButton = '';
                        var deleteButton = '';
                        var saveButton = '';
                        var restoreButton = '';
                        var confirmButton = '';

                        // Add toolbar column header if not exists.
                        if ($table.find('th.tabledit-toolbar-column').length === 0) {
                            $table.find('tr:first').append('<th class="tabledit-toolbar-column"></th>');
                        }

                        // Create edit button.
                        if (settings.editButton) {
                            editButton = '<button type="button" class="tabledit-edit-button ' + settings.buttons.edit.class + '" style="float: none;">' + settings.buttons.edit.html + '</button>';
                        }

                        // Create delete button.
                        if (settings.deleteButton) {
                            deleteButton = '<button type="button" class="tabledit-delete-button ' + settings.buttons.delete.class + '" style="float: none;">' + settings.buttons.delete.html + '</button>';
                            confirmButton = '<button type="button" class="tabledit-confirm-button ' + settings.buttons.confirm.class + '" style="display: none; float: none;">' + settings.buttons.confirm.html + '</button>';
                        }

                        // Create save button.
                        if (settings.editButton && settings.saveButton) {
                            saveButton = '<button type="button" id="buton_save" class="tabledit-save-button ' + settings.buttons.save.class + '" style="display: none; float: none;">' + settings.buttons.save.html + '</button>';
                        }

                        // Create restore button.
                        if (settings.deleteButton && settings.restoreButton) {
                            restoreButton = '<button type="button" class="tabledit-restore-button ' + settings.buttons.restore.class + '" style="display: none; float: none;">' + settings.buttons.restore.html + '</button>';
                        }

                        var toolbar = '<div class="tabledit-toolbar ' + settings.toolbarClass + '" style="text-align: left;">\n\
                                           <div class="' + settings.groupClass + '" style="float: none;">' + editButton + deleteButton + '</div>\n\
                                           ' + saveButton + '\n\
                                           ' + confirmButton + '\n\
                                           ' + restoreButton + '\n\
                                       </div></div>';

                        // Add toolbar column cells.
                        $table.find('tr:gt(0)').append('<td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;">' + toolbar + '</td>');
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        /**
         * Change to view mode or edit mode with table td element as parameter.
         *
         * @type object
         */
        var Mode = {
            view: function(td) {
                // Get table row.
                var $tr = $(td).parent('tr');
                // Disable identifier.
                $(td).parent('tr').find('.tabledit-input.tabledit-identifier').prop('disabled', true);
                // Hide and disable input element.
                $(td).find('.tabledit-input').blur().hide().prop('disabled', true);
                // Show span element.
                $(td).find('.tabledit-span').show();
                // Add "view" class and remove "edit" class in td element.
                $(td).addClass('tabledit-view-mode').removeClass('tabledit-edit-mode');
                // Update toolbar buttons.
                if (settings.editButton) {
                    $tr.find('button.tabledit-save-button').hide();
                    $tr.find('button.tabledit-edit-button').removeClass('active').blur();
                }
            },
            edit: function(td) {
                Delete.reset(td);
                // Get table row.
                var $tr = $(td).parent('tr');
                // Enable identifier.
                $tr.find('.tabledit-input.tabledit-identifier').prop('disabled', false);
                // Hide span element.
                $(td).find('.tabledit-span').hide();
                // Get input element.
                var $input = $(td).find('.tabledit-input');
                // Enable and show input element.
                $input.prop('disabled', false).show();
                // Focus on input element.
                if (settings.autoFocus) {
                    $input.focus();
                }
                // Add "edit" class and remove "view" class in td element.
                $(td).addClass('tabledit-edit-mode').removeClass('tabledit-view-mode');
                // Update toolbar buttons.
                if (settings.editButton) {
                    $tr.find('button.tabledit-edit-button').addClass('active');
                    $tr.find('button.tabledit-save-button').show();
                }
            }
        };

        /**
         * Available actions for edit function, with table td element as parameter or set of td elements.
         *
         * @type object
         */
        var Edit = {
            reset: function(td) {
                $(td).each(function() {
                    // Get input element.
                    var $input = $(this).find('.tabledit-input');
                    // Get span text.
                    var text = $(this).find('.tabledit-span').text();
                    // Set input/select value with span text.
                    if ($input.is('select')) {
                        $input.find('option').filter(function() {
                            return $.trim($(this).text()) === text;
                        }).attr('selected', true);
                    } else {
                        $input.val(text);
                    }
                    // Change to view mode.
                    Mode.view(this);
                });
            },
            submit: function(td) {
                // Send AJAX request to server.
                var ajaxResult = ajax(settings.buttons.edit.action);

                if (ajaxResult === false) {
                    return;
                }

                $(td).each(function() {
                    // Get input element.
                    var $input = $(this).find('.tabledit-input');
                    // Set span text with input/select new value.
                    if ($input.is('select')) {
                        $(this).find('.tabledit-span').text($input.find('option:selected').text());
                    } else {
                        $(this).find('.tabledit-span').text($input.val());
                    }
                    // Change to view mode.
                    Mode.view(this);
                });

                // Set last edited column and row.
                $lastEditedRow = $(td).parent('tr');
            }
        };

        /**
         * Available actions for delete function, with button as parameter.
         *
         * @type object
         */
        var Delete = {
            reset: function(td) {
                // Reset delete button to initial status.
                $table.find('.tabledit-confirm-button').hide();
                // Remove "active" class in delete button.
                $table.find('.tabledit-delete-button').removeClass('active').blur();
            },
            submit: function(td) {
                Delete.reset(td);
                // Enable identifier hidden input.
                $(td).parent('tr').find('input.tabledit-identifier').attr('disabled', false);
                // Send AJAX request to server.
                var ajaxResult = ajax(settings.buttons.delete.action);
                // Disable identifier hidden input.
                $(td).parents('tr').find('input.tabledit-identifier').attr('disabled', true);

                if (ajaxResult === false) {
                    return;
                }

                // Add class "deleted" to row.
                $(td).parent('tr').addClass('tabledit-deleted-row');
                // Hide table row.
                $(td).parent('tr').addClass(settings.mutedClass).find('.tabledit-toolbar button:not(.tabledit-restore-button)').attr('disabled', true);
                // Show restore button.
                $(td).find('.tabledit-restore-button').show();
                // Set last deleted row.
                $lastDeletedRow = $(td).parent('tr');
            },
            confirm: function(td) {
                // Reset all cells in edit mode.
                $table.find('td.tabledit-edit-mode').each(function() {
                    Edit.reset(this);
                });
                // Add "active" class in delete button.
                $(td).find('.tabledit-delete-button').addClass('active');
                // Show confirm button.
                $(td).find('.tabledit-confirm-button').show();
            },
            restore: function(td) {
                // Enable identifier hidden input.
                $(td).parent('tr').find('input.tabledit-identifier').attr('disabled', false);
                // Send AJAX request to server.
                var ajaxResult = ajax(settings.buttons.restore.action);
                // Disable identifier hidden input.
                $(td).parents('tr').find('input.tabledit-identifier').attr('disabled', true);

                if (ajaxResult === false) {
                    return;
                }

                // Remove class "deleted" to row.
                $(td).parent('tr').removeClass('tabledit-deleted-row');
                // Hide table row.
                $(td).parent('tr').removeClass(settings.mutedClass).find('.tabledit-toolbar button').attr('disabled', false);
                // Hide restore button.
                $(td).find('.tabledit-restore-button').hide();
                // Set last restored row.
                $lastRestoredRow = $(td).parent('tr');
            }
        };

        /**
         * Send AJAX request to server.
         *
         * @param {string} action
         */
        function ajax(action)
        {
            var serialize = $table.find('.tabledit-input').serialize() + '&action=' + action;

            var result = settings.onAjax(action, serialize);

            if (result === false) {
                return false;
            }

            var jqXHR = $.post(settings.url, serialize, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (action === settings.buttons.edit.action) {
                    $lastEditedRow.removeClass(settings.dangerClass).addClass(settings.warningClass);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        //$lastEditedRow.removeClass(settings.warningClass);
                        $table.find('tr.' + settings.warningClass).removeClass(settings.warningClass);
                    }, 1400);
                }

                settings.onSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }, 'json');

            jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (action === settings.buttons.delete.action) {
                    $lastDeletedRow.removeClass(settings.mutedClass).addClass(settings.dangerClass);
                    $lastDeletedRow.find('.tabledit-toolbar button').attr('disabled', false);
                    $lastDeletedRow.find('.tabledit-toolbar .tabledit-restore-button').hide();
                } else if (action === settings.buttons.edit.action) {
                    $lastEditedRow.addClass(settings.dangerClass);
                }

                settings.onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            });

            jqXHR.always(function() {
                settings.onAlways();
            });

            return jqXHR;
        }

        Draw.columns.identifier();
        Draw.columns.editable();
        Draw.columns.toolbar();

        settings.onDraw();

        if (settings.deleteButton) {
            /**
             * Delete one row.
             *
             * @param {object} event
             */
            $table.on('click', 'button.tabledit-delete-button', function(event) {
                if (event.handled !== true) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Get current state before reset to view mode.
                    var activated = $(this).hasClass('active');

                    var $td = $(this).parents('td');

                    Delete.reset($td);

                    if (!activated) {
                        Delete.confirm($td);
                    }

                    event.handled = true;
                }
            });

            /**
             * Delete one row (confirm).
             *
             * @param {object} event
             */
            $table.on('click', 'button.tabledit-confirm-button', function(event) {
                if (event.handled !== true) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var $td = $(this).parents('td');

                    Delete.submit($td);

                    event.handled = true;
                }
            });
        }

        if (settings.restoreButton) {
            /**
             * Restore one row.
             *
             * @param {object} event
             */
            $table.on('click', 'button.tabledit-restore-button', function(event) {
                if (event.handled !== true) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    Delete.restore($(this).parents('td'));

                    event.handled = true;
                }
            });
        }

        if (settings.editButton) {
            /**
             * Activate edit mode on all columns.
             *
             * @param {object} event
             */
            $table.on('click', 'button.tabledit-edit-button', function(event) {
                if (event.handled !== true) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var $button = $(this);

                    // Get current state before reset to view mode.
                    var activated = $button.hasClass('active');

                    // Change to view mode columns that are in edit mode.
                    Edit.reset($table.find('td.tabledit-edit-mode'));

                    if (!activated) {
                        // Change to edit mode for all columns in reverse way.
                        $($button.parents('tr').find('td.tabledit-view-mode').get().reverse()).each(function() {
                            Mode.edit(this);
                        });
                    }

                    event.handled = true;
                }
            });

            /**
             * Save edited row.
             *
             * @param {object} event
             */
            $table.on('click', 'button.tabledit-save-button', function(event) {
                if (event.handled !== true) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Submit and update all columns.
                    Edit.submit($(this).parents('tr').find('td.tabledit-edit-mode'));

                    event.handled = true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            /**
             * Change to edit mode on table td element.
             *
             * @param {object} event
             */
            $table.on(settings.eventType, 'tr:not(.tabledit-deleted-row) td.tabledit-view-mode', function(event) {
                if (event.handled !== true) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Reset all td's in edit mode.
                    Edit.submit($table.find('td.tabledit-edit-mode'));

                    // Change to edit mode.
                    Mode.edit(this);

                    event.handled = true;
                }
            });

            /**
             * Change event when input is a select element.
             */
            $table.on('change', 'select.tabledit-input:visible', function() {


                if (event.handled !== true) {
                   



                    var $td = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + (parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1) + ')');                    

                     $td.each(function() {                        
                        window.location.replace('https://class-bit.com/editregistrationAdmin/chage.php?id=' + $(this).text()); 
                           
                    });


                    Edit.reset($(this).parent('td'));
                    event.handled = true;
                }
            });

            /**
             * Click event on document element.
             *
             * @param {object} event
             */
            $(document).on('click', function(event) {
                var $editMode = $table.find('.tabledit-edit-mode');
                // Reset visible edit mode column.
                if (!$editMode.is(event.target) && $editMode.has(event.target).length === 0) {
                    Edit.submit($table.find('.tabledit-input:visible').parent('td'));
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Keyup event on document element.
         *
         * @param {object} event
         */
        $(document).on('keyup', function(event) {
            // Get input element with focus or confirmation button.
            var $input = $table.find('.tabledit-input:visible');
            var $button = $table.find('.tabledit-confirm-button');

            if ($input.length > 0) {
                var $td = $input.parents('td');
            } else if ($button.length > 0) {
                var $td = $button.parents('td');
            } else {
                return;
            }

            // Key?
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 9:  // Tab.
                    if (!settings.editButton) {
                        Edit.submit($td);
                        Mode.edit($td.closest('td').next());
                    }
                    break;
                case 13: // Enter.
                    Edit.submit($td);
                    break;
                case 27: // Escape.
                    Edit.reset($td);
                    Delete.reset($td);
                    break;    
            }
        });

        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una forma de hacerlo en muy pocas líneas de código. A ver si te sirve

```
$("#tabla").on('change', 'select', function(){
  var trID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  // closest(selector) busca el elemento con el selector indicado más cercano a $(this)
  // Luego te traes el dato 'id' del tr con la función attr(dato)
});
```

Dime si te sirve de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Pareciera que solamente se trata de un error de tipeo, tienes un `)` de más en esta línea, luego del `+1`:

`var $td = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1) + ')');`

Arreglándolo quedaría así, prueba si funciona:

```js
$table.on('change', 'select.tabledit-input:visible', function() {
  if (event.handled !== true) {

    var $td = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1 + ')');

    $td.each(function() {
      window.location.replace('https://class-bit.com/editregistrationAdmin/chage.php?id=' + +$(this).text());

    });

    Edit.reset($(this).parent('td'));
    event.handled = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: hola tenias razon un mal tipeo pero sigue mostrandome el ultimo id de la tabla del row en el que presione :(

Comment: bueno creo que tienes que agregar el resto de tu codigo para poder entender mejor lo que estas haciendo

Comment: Agregare mi codigo entero de Jquery ojala me puedas ayudar estoy que reviento el laptop hahah

Comment: Ok XD, oye pero el codigo debes agregarlo en tu misma pregunta, ahi debajo aparece una opcion de editar ahi agregalo

Comment: Listo jahaha gracias por la recomendacion

Comment: y si haces un console.log de `parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1`

Comment: mmmmmm puse eso mismo
console.log(parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1);
y al apretar cualquier fila me tira el id 1

Comment: me muestra siempre 1 yo creo que el console.log toma un 0 y solamente le suma 1 por eso me muestra un 1 ?

Comment: parece que si, desde tus settings el idetinfier viene 0

Comment: exacto, pero si lo hago con este codigo me muestra el ultimo id de la tabla quizas habra que reconstruir solo esa parte ?

var $td = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + parseInt(settings.columns.identifier[0]) + 1 + ')');

Comment: con eso ya toma el id de la tabla identifier pero solo toma el ultimo no el que estoy tomando  :/

Comment: en esa linea esta el problema, revisa como llenas tus settings, talvez ahi esta la raiz

Comment: trabajare en esa linea ahora muchas gracias por los consejos, apenas lo resuelva escribo un comentario  =)

Comment: de nada, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puede funcionar lo siguiente:

```
$("#tabla").on('change', 'select', function(){
  var trElement = $(this).parent().parent();
  trElement.attr('id'); // Aquí tenemos el Id de la fila en la que se seleccionó el select
  //Luego incorporas la lógica que quieras
})
```

Se ejecutará cuando un elemento de la tabla `#tabla`, que sea `select`, haya cambiado su valor.

Comment: Yo cambiaría el `.parent().parent()` por `.parents('tr')`, porque sino puede ocurrir que si se altera el código y hay más padres que engloban el select no te funcionará